# How to reference Google spreadsheet inside your mail message?

Tags: gmail, google-sheets

I would like to embed a Google spreadsheet directly into my email, so that it reflects the document changes. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how you could embed the actual spreadsheet, but you can at least embed a link!

You can capture the link as a web page: File > Publish to the Web... > Capture the link from there to embed in your email.

or - for more granular security control - you can explore the Share feature and capture the link from there.